# Need to set CssClass in toggling DiVs based on CheckBox checked status

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 check boxes (enabled-checked, enabled-unchecked, disabled-checked, disabled-unchecked). I have applied a CSS to transform all check boxes to div with a background image (PNG with alpha). My intention is, the disabled check boxes will have a gray background so that the image looks grayed out.

Here is the JSFiddle link I am working with.

http://jsfiddle.net/manasthemarvel/3uj7ogd0/2/

All works fine except two things:

1. The disabled check boxes are not disabled. I can still click them and the image changes.
2. The enabled-checked and disabled-checked Divs do not show the checked-Tick image on load.

I understand this is happening because on page load I am converting all the check boxes to divs, irrespective of their Checked or Unchecked Status, But How can I fix this?

```
$('.input_class_checkbox').each(function(){
$(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox"/>');    
});
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp like this?

Comment: No Javascript at all required here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For point 2, edited script to add an additional class for checked state.
http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/3uj7ogd0/4/

```
$('.input_class_checkbox').each(function(){
   var c = $(this).attr('disabled') ? '' : 'checked';
   $(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox ' + c + '" />');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the 1 st and 4th checkbox should be checked. The fiddle has 3rd and 4th checked :-/

Comment: You are right - Updated the fiddle. - [http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/3uj7ogd0/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/3uj7ogd0/16/)

Comment: Now the disabled boxes have become clickable again :'( :'(

Comment: Added one more condition in js - `if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled'))` - [http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/3uj7ogd0/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/3uj7ogd0/16/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following **JS** in your code

```
$('.input_class_checkbox').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        if($(this).is(":disabled")){
             $(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox checked disabled"/>');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox checked"/>');            
        }
    }
    else{
        if($(this).is(":disabled")){
             $(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox disabled"/>');
        }
        else
        {
             $(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox"/>');   
        }
    }
});

$('.class_checkbox').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('checked').prev().prop('checked',$(this).is('.checked'));
    }
});

$( "input:disabled" ).next().css( "background-color", "gray" );
```

See the **fiddle** I have modified http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/3uj7ogd0/12/

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure css & html solution that also does not require images.. It needs some visual perfecting, but otherwise this is what you want probably.

http://jsfiddle.net/3uj7ogd0/15/

```css
.input_class_checkbox {
    display: none;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
}
.input_class_checkbox + label:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.input_class_checkbox:disabled + label:after {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-color: #888;
    color: #888;
}
.input_class_checkbox:checked + label:after {
    content: "✓";
}

.input_class_checkbox:checked + label + p {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input_class_checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" id="a1" />
    <label for="a1"></label>
    <p>Disabled checked</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input_class_checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="a2" />
    <label for="a2"></label>
    <p>Disabled Unchecked</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input_class_checkbox" id="a3" />
    <label for="a3"></label>
    <p>Active checkbox - Unchecked</p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input_class_checkbox" checked="checked" id="a4" />
    <label for="a4"></label>
    <p>Active checkbox - Checked</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
$('.class_checkbox').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).attr('disabled') == false){
        $(this).toggleClass('checked').prev().prop('checked',$(this).is('.checked'));
    }
});
```